# How to set image for custom image view in android

Tags: android

Hi friends
can anybody tell how to set image for custom image view  dynamically in android can anybody give example

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your custom image view extends the normal image view the setting should be exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

if you, like WarrenFaith said extend the normal image view, here's the code:

```
customImageView.setImageBitmap(mIcon1);
```